# Drupal Module for Zoom Print and Save

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, view

i would like to ask about module on Drupal. I need to add "Zoom", "Print", and "Save" functionalities. I am sure there must be a module to handle this. Is there any solution about which module I should use? For information, i am using Drupal 7 and need to add the functionalities to Views page. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module for printing: http://drupal.org/project/print
This also gives provision to save as pdf & email the article.